# How to loop using recursion in ACL2?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, acl2

I need to make something like this but in ACL2:

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    print i;
}
```

It uses COMMON LISP, but I haven't any idea how to do this task...

We can't use standard Common Lisp constructions such as LOOP, DO. Just recursion.

I have some links, but I find it very difficult to understand:

- [Gentle Intro to ACL2 Programming](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/publications/gentle-intro-to-acl2-programming.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section "Visiting all the natural numbers from n to 0" in [A Gentle Introduction to ACL2 Programming](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/publications/gentle-intro-to-acl2-programming.html) explains how to do it.

In your case you want to visit numbers in ascending order, so your code should look something like this:

```
(defun visit (n max ...)
  (cond ((> n max) ...)             ; N exceeds MAX: nothing to do.
        (t .                        ; N less than or equal to MAX:
            . n                     ; do something with N, and
             .
              (visit (+ n 1) max ...) ; visit the numbers above it.
             .
            .
           .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses recursion:

```
> (defun for-loop (from to fn)
    (if (<= from to)
       (progn
         (funcall fn from)
         (for-loop (+ from 1) to fn))))

;; Test
> (for-loop 1 10 #'(lambda (i) (format t "~a~%" i)))
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
NIL
```

Comment: ACL2 Error in ( DEFUN FOR-LOOP ...):  IF takes 3 arguments but in the
call (IF (<= FROM TO) (PROGN (FUNCALL FN FROM) (FOR-LOOP (+ FROM 1) TO FN)))
it is given 2 arguments.   The formal parameters list for IF is (X Y Z).                                                             Its prints by ACL2 system. When i try add third arguments to IF (just 'nil to the end )

Comment: its return - ACL2 p!>(defun for-loop (from to fn)
    (if (<= from to)
       (progn
         (funcall fn from)
         (for-loop (+ from 1) to fn)) 'nil) )


ACL2 Error in ( DEFUN FOR-LOOP ...):  We do not permit the use of PROGN
inside of code to be executed by Common Lisp because its Common Lisp
meaning differs from its ACL2 meaning.

Answer (score 1):

(defun foo-loop (n)
  (cond ((zp n) "done")
         (t (prog2$ (cw "~x0" n)
                    (foo-loop (1- n)))))

(foo-loop 10)

You can redo the termination condition and the recursion to mimic going from 1 to 10.